# adding functions to a knex/bookshelf model in node/express

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have a model like this:

```
const User = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    hasSecurePassword: true
});

module.exports = User;
```

With this I can do things like

```
const User      = require("../models/user");

 User.fetchAll({columns:['id','email']}).then((data) => {
        res.json(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.json(err);
    });
```

What if I want to add costume functions to my model such as:

```
var connection  = require('./dbconnection.js');
var User = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    hasSecurePassword: true
});


User.getUsers = (callback) => {
    if (connection) {
        const newLocal = "select * FROM users";
        connection.query(newLocal, (err,rows,fields) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            } else {
                callback(null,rows);
            }
        });
    }
};

module.exports = User;
```

And then do something like:

```
 const User      = require("../models/user");
 User.getUsers((err,data) => {
    res.status(200).json(data);
});
```

Is this posible? Or should I just conform with the bookshelf functions?
Right now the error I get is `connection.query is not a function`

And models/dbconnection.js is:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
port = process.env.PORT || 3333;


if (port == 3333) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        insecureAuth: true
    });
} else {
    console.log("Error");
}

connection.connect();
module.exports.connection = connection;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add your custom functions to bookshelf models in two different ways.

1. Instance methods

For example, you want to return user's full name, your User model will look something like this

```
const User = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    hasSecurePassword: true,

    //be careful here, if you use arrow function `this` context will change 
    //and your function won't work as expected

    returnFullName: function() {
       return this.get('firstname') + this.get('lastname');
    }
});

module.exports = User;
```

then you will call this function like this

```
User.forge().where({id: SOME_ID}).fetch()
    .then(function(user) {
        var fullName = user.returnFullName();
    });
```

2. Class methods

For example, you want to return user's email based on username, your User model will look something like this

```
const User = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    hasSecurePassword: true
}, {

    getUserEmail: function(SOME_USERNAME) {
        return User.forge().where({username: SOME_USERNAME}).fetch()
            .then(function (user) {
                if(user) {
                    return Promise.resolve(user.get('email'));
                } else {
                    return Promise.resolve(null);
                }
            });
    }        
});

module.exports = User;
```

then you can call this function like

```
User.getUserEmail(SOME_USERNAME)
    .then(function(email) {
        console.log(email);
    });
```

Comment: Note that there is no need for `Promise.resolve()`. You can just return the values directly since you're already inside a Promise.